# Google Map/Places autocomplete not appearing in overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

**** UPDATE
Partially resolved. This bit of code was forcing the position. Didn't see it previously.

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

Might help someone else at some point.

---

Im working on a Google Maps implementation, where Im displaying a map of the world showing my custom placemarkers. I have an add button, that when selected opens an overlay over the map with some basic form capture (name, event etc).

I also have a location field which Ive linked up to to Google places API for the address lookup.

The field is named as per the guidelines as pac input

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="location">Location</label>
        <input id="pac-input" placeholder="Enter your address" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" type="text"></input>
</div>
```

The overlay is triggered and displayed onClick, however the input field is missing from the overlay, and appears on the map directly.

Inside the initmap function called when the map is initialised, the input field is defined.

```
var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
```

If I remove this from the initMap, the field appears in the overlay, but the autocomplete doesnt fire.

Im sure its something straight forward, but haven't played with the maps API for quite some time.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share some more code?

Comment: Thanks Akshay, Ive partially resolved it and updated the post, sneaky bit of code overriding the HTML elements.